# How to obtain McAfee Agent version on remote system using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I found a PowerShell script from a previous user that was able to find McAfee Agent version on local machine. The script is below:

```powershell
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
  Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
    Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "McAfee*"}
```

However, how do I obtain this information on a remote system, such as: another workstation or server.

For example, I'd like to execute this PS script on my workstation to obtain McAfee Agent version information on a remote system, such as another workstation and/or server.

Comment: Use [`Invoke-Command -ComputerName ... `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command?view=powershell-5.1), which, however requires that the target machine is [set up for remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about_Remote_Requirements?view=powershell-5.1).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ComputerName = "localhost" #Example
$MCAfeeInfo =Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
$ReturnValue = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "McAfee*"}
Return $ReturnValue    
}
```

Make sure that you run the script as administrator and remote powershell is enabled on the target computer